# DI using constructor not works because object required parameter less constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, abp

There is a class that uses some dependencies that will come from the constructor.

```cs
public class FooHttpApiHostModule : AbpModule
{
    private readonly ICustomContext _customContext;

    public FooHttpApiHostModule(ICustomContext customContext)
    {
        _customContext = customContext;
    }

    // Some other code here.
}
```

Inside the `ApplicationModule`, There is a scope added for it.

```cs
public class FooApplicationModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        context.Services
            .AddScoped<ICustomContext, CustomContext>();
    }
}
```

But when the code is running, next exception occur:

> **`System.MissingMethodException`:** Cannot dynamically create an instance of type `FooHttpApiHostModule`.
> Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.

The exception happens inside the `Startup` class on next line.

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplication<FooHttpApiHostModule>(); // <-- Exception on this line.
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to inject `ICustomContext` into `FooHttpApiHostModule`?

---

**Update 1:**

When writing this line in the `ConfigureServices` of my `FooHttpApiHostModule`

```cs
var graphContext = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ICustomContext>();
```

Next error occur

> **`System.ArgumentNullException`:** Value cannot be null.
> (Parameter `provider`)

Full code:

```cs
public class FooHttpApiHostModule : AbpModule
{
    // Removed constructor and private readonly variable.

    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        ICustomContext customContext = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ICustomContext>(); // <-- exception on this line.
    }

    // Other code here...
}
```

Did an extra check and `ICustomContext` is added to the scope.

[image: context.Services.IsAdded<ICustomContext>() == true]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use constructor injection like as you did for `FooHttpApiHostModule`.

Instead, you should use code like the below:

```
public class FooHttpApiHostModule : AbpModule
{

     public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
     {
        var customContext = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ICustomContext>()
        // customContext.Do();
        // Some other code here.
     }
}
```

Reference:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#resolve-a-service-at-app-start-up

Comment: I've got a `System.ArgumentNullException` with message _Value cannot be null. (Parameter `provider`)_.

Comment: Found the problem. Using `GetServiceLazy<ICustomContext>()` instead solved the problem. It's a +1 and acceptance from me .